# VueJS - is there a way to force a mixin reload?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a pagination mixin that takes a list name and a number of element per page as arguments and returns all the methods and data I need to have some pagination on that list.

I'm using it in a vue components, and depending on the viewport width I'm using it with 2 or 4 elements per page.

So my components checks the windowWidth when it's created, and the load the mixin accordingly. My issue is that it works fine most of the time, but when the user resizes the window it doesn't updates the number of element per pages since it doesn't reload the mixin, which makes the mobile/computer layout break.

Here's my code :

```
<script>
import { paginationMixin } from "../../assets/mixins";

const mixin4 = paginationMixin("images", 4);
const mixin2 = paginationMixin("images", 2);
let loadMixin = window.innerWidth < 550 ? mixin2 : mixin4;

export default {
  props: ["images"],
  data() {
    return {
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
      activeImage: 0,
      tempActiveImage: null
    };
  },
  mixins: [loadMixin],
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    });
  },
  computed: {
    imageShow() {
      if (this.tempActiveImage !== null) {
        return this.tempActiveImage;
      } else {
        return this.activeImage;
      }
    },
    elementPerPage() {
      return this.windowWidth < 550 ? 2 : 4;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Basically I would like to add some lines in the resize event listener so that it also change the mixin I'm using if I'm passing the windowWidth threshold.
I tried using :

```
if (
        (this.windowWidth >= 550 && window.innerWidth < 550) ||
        (this.windowWidth < 550 && window.innerWidth >= 550)
      ) {
        console.log("mobile changed");
        loadMixin = window.innerWidth < 550 ? mixin2 : mixin4;
        this.$forceUpdate();
      }
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Answer (score 2):

I would consider just moving this logic to the `mixin`. So load the `mixin` like this:

```
<script>
import coolMixins from "../../assets/mixins";

export default {
  props: ["images"],
  data() {
    return {
      activeImage: 0,
      tempActiveImage: null
    };
  },
  mixins: [coolMixins],
  computed: {
    imageShow() {
      if (this.tempActiveImage !== null) {
        return this.tempActiveImage;
      } else {
        return this.activeImage;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Then inside of your mixin do the resizing logic:

```
mounted() {
   window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
},
methods: {
  onResize(event) {
    const itemsToShow = window.innerWidth < 550 ? 2 : 4;
    this.paginationMixin("images", itemsToShow);
  }
}
```

Another benefit to this is that you won't get duplicated code in each consumer of the mixin, and if you need to make the number of items to show dynamic then the consumer could just pass that info to the mixin.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you here. So CoolMixins would be my actual mixin ? and paginationMixin a method that changes the values values in my mixin ? 


Also, the thing is I don't need this logic in the other components that uses this mixin. The element on page depending on the window size is really specific to this component. Would your method still work ?

Comment: Yeah - `coolMixin` (obviously rename it) would be your whole mixin you want to include. `paginationMixin` is whatever function you're trying to call inside of your mixin that sets the `itemsToShow`. If you only need this logic in one component, then I would question why have any of this logic living in the mixin, if that's the case just move the logic that is only used in the component to live inside of the component rather than the mixin and your problem goes away.

Comment: I actually use the mixin in a lot of components, what is specific to that one component is using different pagination mixin parameters depending on the window width.